How do you prevent 4x4 fence post from rotting on the bottom?
I have to replace 8-10 posts due to rot. Some of these are set in concrete, some are not.
I have read you should seal posts with tar or oil based sealant on the bottom before setting in concrete. I have also read that you shouldn't seal because the post will retain water. So I am confused as what to do when I replace these posts:





go and take look at railroad tracks. With what are the Woden beams coated ?

@Traveler  A lot of the the stuff that did a good job sealing/protecting wood, is not allowed or looked at kindly these days.  Even creosoted railway ties do rot in time, and the full size ones are quite heavy.

For the ones set in concrete, it can help to kind of dome the concrete above grade so that water rolls off the concrete.

In roughly decreasing order of importance:
Not all pressure treated wood is the same. If it's going to be buried, or touch the ground, you need pressure treated posts rated for Ground Contact - they will NOT be the cheapest pressure treated posts you can find.
If using concrete at all, it should be an open-bottomed collar around the post, so that water can drain away. Sticking a post into concrete so the concrete makes a cup to hold water around the post is not good for post life.
You can paint or dip the ends of the post in or with roofing tar. If doing that, do the top as well as the bottom. Actually a good use of tar-based "tree wound dressing" which should not be used on trees (per quite a lot of experimental evidence, but that makes no difference to the people that sell it to people who don't look at the evidence and just see "product to buy which lies about what it does - must be what I need!)
Alternatively: You can use a galvanized or stainless steel post below ground, set in concrete if you like, and keep the bottom of the wood post (attached to the steel post) 4" or so above ground so it never touches the ground.

also, concrete posts are a thing.  mine show no signe of significant deteriation after 50+ years just slight surface roughness and some lichen.  the bolts holdinh the fence rails on are not looking well and the rails nealry rotted though,
